# Query with foreign keys in Ecto Models

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have the following Ecto schemas:

```
schema "videos" do
    field :name, :string
    field :mpdName, :string
    field :urlPlayready, :string, size: 500
    field :urlWidevine, :string, size: 500
    field :urlFile, :string, size: 500
    field :custom_data, :string, size: 500
    field :drm_today, :boolean
    field :vote, :integer
    has_many :user_videos, VideoBackend.UserVideos
    has_many :users, through: [:user_videos, :user]
    timestamps
  end


schema "users"  do
   field :name, :string
   field :email, :string ,  [:primary_key]
   field :encrypted_password, :string
   field :password, :string, virtual: true
   has_many :user_videos, VideoBackend.UserVideos
   has_many :videos, through: [:user_videos, :video]
   timestamps   
end

schema "user_videos" do
  belongs_to :users, VideoBackend.User
  belongs_to :videos, VideoBackend.Video
  field :time, :float
  field :device, :integer
  timestamps
end
```

Now I want to make a query that select the user_videos given a specific "user" and a specific "video". In SQL I would write this simple query:

> SELECT FROM user_videos WHERE user = "user" and video = "video"

I tried to write the following Ecto query but it does not work:

```
def single_userVideo(user,video) do
    from u in UserVideos,
    where: u.user == ^user and u.video == ^video
end
```

Do you know how I could solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `has_many` and `belongs_to` then you probably want to query based on the `_id` columns.

So the SQL would be:

> SELECT FROM user_videos WHERE user_id = "user" and video_id = "video"

And the query:

```
def single_user_video(%{id: user_id}, %{id: video_id}) do
  from u in UserVideos,
  where: u.user_id == ^user_id,
  where: u.video_id == ^video_id
end
```

When [where/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#where/3) is used more than once in a query it will use `AND` in the query.

> where expressions are used to filter the result set. If there is more than one where expression, they are combined with an and operator. All where expressions have to evaluate to a boolean value.

As an aside, functions in Elxir are written in `snake_case` so `single_userVideos` should be `single_user_videos`

Comment: The problem is that it throws me this error:

"field VideoBackend.UserVideos.user in where does not exist in the model source in query: from u in VideoBackend.UserVideos, where: u.user == ^1, where: u.video == ^1 "
Does it happen because I didn't add "user" and "video" fields in the "user_videos" model?

Comment: You should be using `user_id` and `video_id` as I specified in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. It was a problem of convention. In my case I have to use users_id and videos_id